# Kmail says no akonadi agent is available

Tags: debian, debian-stretch, kmail

When I launch KMail, it says that no akonadi agent is available.
I checked with akonadictl status and akonadi is running with no problem.
What can I do ?
There's a Details button but nothing happens when I click.